# Python: get random number from range (or two ranges) and single number

Tags: python, random, addition

I have that little script that generates me a random number from sets of ranges like:
(1-6).

Now I would like to read not only one range, but add another range or single numbers like:
('1-6', '10', '12-17')

My Script looks like that so far, "choose_frame_set" is the parameter for the ranges:

```
def retime_frames():

    # choose frame set from presets
    fr_range = hou.evalParm("choose_frame_set")


    # extract frame range from list into readable string
    fr_sequence = []

    for frames in fr_range.split(','):
        if '-' in frames:
            a, b = frames.split('-')
            a, b = int(a), int(b)
            fr_sequence.extend(range(a, b + 1))
        else:
            a = int(frames)

    # set random frame from frame range
    random_frame = str(random.sample(fr_sequence, 1))

    # replace special characters
    for char in '[]':  
        random_frame = random_frame.replace(char,'')

    hou.parm('retime_frame').set(random_frame)
    print random_frame
    return random_frame
```

How can I add extra ranges or single numbers, to have more control about what numbers I randomize?

[image: retime_frame]

Comment: Seems, your code works if change `else: a = int(frames)` to `else:
            fr_sequence.append(int(frames))`

Comment: That works perfect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the choice method:

```
from random import choice

def ran(*r):
    num = []
    for n in r:
        num += [m for m in range(n[0],n[1]+1)]
    return choice(num)

print(ran((1,4),(5,7),(12,13)))
```

All possible output: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,12,13

Answer (score 0):

Referring to splash58's comment under my question, the solution is:

> Seems, your code works if change `else: a = int(frames)` to `else:
>
>   fr_sequence.append(int(frames))`